# Dashboard primefaces : How to add a line between columns in dashboard?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dashboard

How to add a line between columns in dashboard
in showcase at:  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dashboard.jsf

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of line you mean. Do you mean the dark gray border around the Column Text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add border style to ui-dashboard-column class using css,like

```
.ui-dashboard-column
{
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
...
}
```

style according to your needs